# Why does List Capacity resize to much more than is needed?

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to fill a list with 10000 random integers in the range of 0 to 20000. Here is the code for how I do it:

```
List<int> rand_num = new List<int>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i =0;
        //int counter = 0;
        while (i < 10000)
        {
            rand_num.Add(rand.Next(0, 20000));
            i++;
        }

        textBox1.Text = rand_num.Capacity.ToString();
```

The problem is when it gets to the `textBox1.Text = rand_num.Capacity.ToString();` line, the output is 16384. I have only entered 10000 numbers, how can it re size to 6384 more than what I need? Am I missing something about how lists behave in c#?

Comment: A .NET list (or at least this one) doubles its size when it needs more size. That's why the property is called `Capacity`, it indicates how many items the list **can** hold. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1665325/209103

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is how much the list *can* hold, before it needs to be resized internally.

> Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds
>   Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by
>   automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old
>   elements and adding the new elements.

What you are looking for is [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns the amount of elements *currently* in the list.

```
textBox1.Text = rand_num.Count.ToString();
```

When the number of elements needs to become more than the capacity, .NET will resize the internal array so it can hold more values, which is generally an expensive operation. The Capacity property can also be set if you know in advance the maximum amount of values you will need.

Comment: It should be the `Count` property, not the `Count()` method. `Count()` will iterate the entire list.

Comment: @DanielMann, fixed, misspell on my part, was thinking of LINQ

Comment: But don't I have extra unused space in my list now? how can I make count equal to capacity?

Comment: I think it's less expensive to have a higher capacity than count, as reallocating the entire array each time you add an item is less efficient than just having some "fluff" space in the array

Comment: @Finalreq, I'm not exactly sure, but I'd imagine it's not a good idea. You will generate more garbage by resizing the array than by just leaving a bit of empty values in memory.

Comment: @Finalreq If it is *essential* that you remove the excess space, you can use the [List(Of T).TrimExcess Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207.aspx), but please take note of the remarks in that documentation.

Comment: @DanielMann the LINQ `Count()` method has optimizations to not iterate the collection if the size is known (if the type implements `ICollection` I believe).

Comment: @Finalreq If you want to make count equal capacity and you know how many items will be in the final list just use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. `List<int> rand_num = new List<int>(10000);`. That will set `Capacity` to 10000 to start with and the list will only start resizing after you add the 10001th item.

Answer (score 10):

Internally, the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class stores its items in an array. Because arrays are a fixed size, adding new items is very expensive, as it requires allocating a new array and copying all the previous items into the new array. To get around this, the `List<T>` class grows it's array exponentially, doubling in size only once the number of items surpasses it's internal array's capacity.

In other words, [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't refer to the number of items in the list. It refers to the number of items the list can store without having to reallocate it's internal array. Also note that you know ahead of time approximately how many items you need to store in the array, you can specify the initial capacity in the list's [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx), to avoid lots of costly reallocations (the default is 4).

Use the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get the number of items in the list at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using:

```
textBox1.Text = rand_num.Count.ToString();
```