# Why rehash has quadratic complexity, but operator [] has linear complexity in worst case?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, std, unordered-map

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164822/why-hastables-rehash-complexity-may-be-quadratic-in-worst-case) question, but mine is a bit different.

Why does [`rehash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/rehash#Complexity) have quadratic complexity, but [`operator []`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at#Complexity) (which can call `rehash`) has linear complexity in worst case?

Sorry, but I don't have 10 points for adding images, so if by the time you look at this question everything was already fixed, here is what I saw at cppreference:

`rehash` complexity:

> Average case linear in the size of the container, worst case quadratic.

`operator[]` complexity:

> Average case: constant, worst case: linear in size.

I know why rehash can have quadratic complexity. However, it is not difficult to make it linear. Therefore, either statement can be true, but not both together (only if different sizes are meant, but then I don't understand what can be taken as a size, except for the number of elements).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256880/discussion-on-question-by-bash-mac-why-rehash-has-quadratic-complexity-but-oper); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.