# underscore.js filter an array of objects, based on another

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to filter an array of objects, based on another. The common property id `id`.
I am not sure filter + each is the best way to do it or map reduce. Anyway, below code doesn't work as `out` is empty list.

```
var aaa = [
    {name: "AAA", id: 845},
    {name: "BBB", id: 839},
    {name: "CCC", id: 854}
];
var bbb = [
    {id: 839},
    {id: 854}
];

var out = _.filter(aaa, function(val){
    return _.each(this, function(val2){
        return val['id'] === val2['id']
    });
}, bbb);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just create a "set" of the valid ids and use that "set" to do the filtering:

```
var aaa = [
    {name: "AAA", id: 845},
    {name: "BBB", id: 839},
    {name: "CCC", id: 854}
];
var bbb = [
    {id: 839},
    {id: 854}
];

var ids = {};
_.each(bbb, function (bb) { ids[bb.id] = true; });

var out = _.filter(aaa, function (val) {
    return ids[val.id];
}, bbb);
```

Filling `ids` is fast, it's in n * [amortized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949217/time-complexity-of-hash-table) O(1), i.e O(n). Same holds for the filtering.

If you use `each(…)` in the inner loop, you will have O(n²). For bigger data sets this would become very slow. Also the additional nesting make the code more difficult to read/understand at first glance.

See that code snipped in action: http://jsfiddle.net/SMtX5/

Comment: thans for the explanation and reasoning behind.

Answer (score 20):

you can use `_.find` to filter:

```
_.filter(aaa, function(a){
    return _.find(bbb, function(b){
        return b.id === a.id;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.some(list, [iterator], [context])`](http://underscorejs.org/#some).

It returns *true* if any of the values in the **list** pass the **iterator** truth test.

```
var out = _.filter(aaa, function(val){
    return _.some(this,function(val2){
        return val2['id'] === val['id'];
    });
}, bbb);
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/h98ej/

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, ow much faster is this routine vs what was accepted?

Answer (score 2):

```
bbb = bbb.map(_ => _.id) && aaa.filter(_ => bbb.indexOf( _.id ) > -1)
```

You just need pure JS array functions to do that assuming your use case.