# How to filter collection based on another collection using underscore.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection called `mainItems``

```
this.mainItems;
```

which contains 18 models. And also one more collection object which contains selected items:

```
this.seletedItems;
```

I need to filter the main collection object based on other collection.

I have tried the below approach:

```
    var that = this;
    var model = _.reject(that.filteredItems.models, function(model1){
        return _.filter(that.collection.models, function(model2) {
           return model1.id == model2.id;
        });
    });
```

but this approach is not working properly. Is it possible to filter the main items by avoiding second iteration ?

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [underscore.js with two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851118/underscore-js-with-two-arrays)

Comment: Looks more like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103511/underscore-js-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Underscore's methods proxied by Backbone to simplify your filter.

For example, to list the models in `mainItems` without the models in `selectedItems`, you could use

```
// reject the models found in selectedItems
var filtered = mainItems.reject(function(m) {
    return selectedItems.get(m.id);
});
```

Note that [`Collection.get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) is a hash lookup, making this a Backbone equivalent to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103511/underscore-js-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-another) pointed by @GruffBunny in the comments.

And a demo

```js
var mainItems = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}
]);

var selectedItems = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 2}
]);

var keep = mainItems.reject(function(m) {
    return selectedItems.get(m.id);
});

console.log(_.pluck(keep, 'id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: somehow backbone methods are not working and I have modified the script using underscore.js with _.reject and _.bind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**difference**](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) to get all the models that are not selected.

```js
var mainItems = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];
var selectedItems = mainItems.slice(1);

console.log(_.difference(mainItems, selectedItems));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Difference won't work here as the arrays contain objects and not literals.

Comment: @GruffBunny That's true. My example was not good. It works with references also, though.

Comment: @GruffBunny It really depends on details that the OP has actually not provided in the question. In my apps, this solution would work because models are not ever duplicated on the client: if two collections contain the same model, it must be the same JavaScript object. If the OP's `selectedItems` is produced by taking a model from `mainItems` and adding it to `selectedItems` then comparing by reference works. If not, it does not work.