# What is the Time complexity of inserting and searching in Hash Table?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable

**I have seen many questions regarding worst case time complexity using hash table to inserting and search in O(N) time** ?

But, i have a doubt why is it done so as in the worst case time complexity for hash table becomes O(N^2).

Then, why we go for O(N). **Can anyone provide a good reason for this** ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you explain where your conclusion comes from?

Comment: @harold, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234116/is-finding-a-pair-of-equal-integers-in-an-array-on

Comment: Ok so how does that lead to quadratic insertion time?

Comment: How you got O(n^2) involved? Degenerate hashmap has O(n) complexity for operations.

Comment: @harold, In the worst case, hashtable insertion can be same as linked list insertion .

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, In the worst case, hashtable insertion can be same as linked list insertion, right ?

Comment: Sure, worst case. What do you think happens if you insert a million items that all have the same hash value?

Comment: @gnasher729, Yes i know that, but time complexity is all about O, right ?So, why hash table are good then ?

Comment: Problem is that it is not clear what you mean here. You are thinking about complexity of inserting n items into hashtable (which indeed is somewhere between O(n) and O(n^2)), but it is not mentioned here. If you just ask about 'complexity of inserting items into hashtable', then people will interpret it as complexity of inserting _single_ item after you have n items already in the table. In any case, taking linked question into account, you should not worry about hashtable worst case performance. Chances of it happening is decreasing with n. If it is purely academic exercise, use radix sort.

Comment: @gnasher729, I have seen people saying, that hash table can do this operation in linear time, but we always find TC based on worst case, so why is it linear time ?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, I have seen people saying, that hash table can do this operation in linear time, but we always find TC based on worst case, so why is it linear time ?

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, Radix sort works best, when size of digits is known before .

Comment: So, is your question really 'why inserting single element into hashmap can degenerate to have O(n) complexity' or are you asking 'if hashmap can degenerate to linear complexity, why people are suggesting it as a solution to problems?'

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, Can u please tell how it can be regenerated from O(N^2) to O(N) in the worst case, i.e putting all the elements in a single slot ?

Comment: With integers, you have perfect hashcode function, so only chance of getting things really wrong is having some pathological distribution of integers which exactly fit modulo hashtable size. This can possibly happen with power-of-two hashtable more easily if you don't double-hash hashcodes themselves. With prime-number size hashtable it is generally enough to rehash table with bigger size to get rid of degenerate layout.