# Codility performance difference: array vs hash

Tags: ruby, performance, big-o

I made a test in codility: https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/ and I noticed a performance difference between two different solutions:

1 - List solution:

```
def solution(list)
  unmatched_elements = []
  list.each{ |el|
    if unmatched_elements.include? el
      unmatched_elements.delete el
    else
      unmatched_elements.push el
    end
  }
  unmatched_elements[0]
end
```

2 - Hash Solution

```
def solution(a)
  unmatch = {}

  a.each do |e|
    if unmatch[e].nil?
      unmatch[e] = 1
    else
      unmatch.delete e
    end
  end
  unmatch.keys.first
end
```

The first one gave me 25% performance score with some timeouts. The second one gave me 100% performance score. Why is that? I tought pushing to a Hash would result in O(n) space complexity like a List, but it seems it's not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about space complexity, it's about time complexity. Specifically, looking up an element in an array (`include?`) is a N time operation since it needs to check each element until there's a match. Hash lookup `[]` is constant time.

This answer explains why Hash has O(1) search time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4363602/1034681

Comment: In the test conditions it says: "expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space complexity is O(1);". That's why I tought the space was the problem. Since the test returned timeouts in array case it means array search can be worst than O(N) ?

Comment: unfortunately i don't know.

Comment: @Jirico: it doesn't make sense to talk about "O(N) expected worst-case time complexity" without specifying a) what you mean by "N" and b) what you mean by "time". In general, when talking about algorithmic complexity, you always need to specify a machine model (which tells you which operations are allowed) and a cost model (which tells you how costly each of the allowed operations is). You also need to specify what assumptions you can make on your data, and lastly, you need to specify how you define "input size". For example: in a Turing Machine, copying a list takes O(n²) steps, not O(n). …

Comment: In the standard Random-Access-Machine model (the most widely used since it is the one closest to how modern mainstream general purpose computers work), comparison-based sorting takes O(n log n) comparisons. But in a machine model without random access, where you are only allowed to swap adjacent elements, comparison-based sorting takes O(n²) comparisons. OTOH, if you can assume a certain kind of structure on your items, then you can sort in O(n) time (e.g. radix sort, counting sort) without using comparisons. In your specific case, you need to iterate over every element of `list` and in …

Comment: … every iteration of the loop, you need to iterate twice over every element of `unmatched_elements` (once for `include?` and again for `delete?`). `unmatched_elements` can grow and shrink, so the analysis is non-obvious, but the worst-case is if the array looks like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, …, 1000000, 1234567890, 1000000, 999999, 999998, …]`, so it can grow to `list.size / 2` in the worst case. That means, your complexity is O(list.size * 2*unmatched_elements.size) which is O(list.size²)!