# Swift set contains complexity

Tags: swift, data-structures, time-complexity

Set has contains function which returns true if member exists in the set; otherwise, false.

and its complexity is O(1).

I want to know how its complexity is constant O(1) i.e. it does not depends on size

Here are the docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains

Comment: Who says that the complexity is O(1)? It strongly depends on the distribution of the hash values of the elements.

Comment: @MartinR Who says? [The documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540013-contains) If that's incorrect, a documentation bug report should be filed.

Comment: docs link added in question

Comment: Disclaimer: it's at the bottom, under the code example.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka it's not O(1) on every iteration. It's O(1) *on average*, assuming that you have a good hash function. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771368/can-hash-tables-really-be-o1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363539/how-does-hashing-have-an-o1-search-time), also [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md) for improvement to Swift `hashValue`.

Comment: [Dictionary.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift) mentions that *"Native storage is a hash table with open addressing and linear probing."* and I think the same is true for `Set`. If all elements have the same hash value then the lookup degenerates to O(N).

Comment: @CodeDifferent I'm not taking a stand on whether it's O(1) or not. I'm pointing out that the documentation _states_ it's O(1), and that if this is demonstrably untrue, then someone should file a report against the documentation. Because as long as the documentation claims the complexity is O(1), it's not unreasonable to assume the complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score 5):

It will use hash function to insert, search. Good hash function will lead to 0(1) time complexity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 1):

If you see the header of Apple documentation.
You should see *Collection / Set*.

So this is not an **Array** where **contains** method have a complexity of O(n).

A **Set** use hash table with low complexity to insert, search and delete a value.

I add 2 Apple documentations one for contains method from Set and other one for Array.

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/contains(_:)
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/contains(_:)