# .NET Dictionary, impressively fast but how does it work?

Tags: .net, memory, dictionary, performance

Ok, I will confess I've not dug out reflector to look at what's going on here, but I'm hoping someone can tell me.

How do Microsoft make adding and fetching so fast, I can make adding fast by just sticking items in an array, and I can make fetching fast by sorting the array and using a binary search. If however, I was to do a quicksort every time an item was added to make fetching data fast, adding would slow down massively, and if I had to sort the data every time I tried to fetch something, adding items would slow massively.

Does anyone know the internal workings of a dictionary? It is a fair bit more memory hungry than an array, so there's clearly something other than clever algorithms going on behind the scenes.

I'm trying to understand the magic and learn from it!

Comment: Very simply: It depends on the concept that, in order to compare two objects every time, you could instead just compare their "fingerprints", which is immensely faster. Only if there's a collision do you actually need to compare the objects, hence the speed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `dictionary<T,T>` in .Net is a data structure called a hash table:

On Hash Table and .Net Dictionary:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yh14awz.aspx

http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/hash_tables.html

On Binary Search:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search

You're right, it uses more memory than an array to retrieve data.  That's the trade off you pay for faster access. (This is true in most cases, when you start taking into account the setup time to build a hash table vs an array, at times a sorted array could be faster for setup time and access.  In general this is a valid assumption though.)

Comment: One more link, referring to the concept you mentioned: The [space-time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff) is a classic concept in CS.

Answer (score 36):

Not so long ago I've sworn on my mother's grave to bring a detailed answer to this question, it took me quite a while since some of the details and concepts were a bit rusty on my end but, anyhoo without any further ado, here it goes:

**How the .NET Dictionary works in length, or kind of...**

First things first, let's start off with the concept, like so many other answers have already pointed out, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a generic (in the sense of the C# language feature) implementation of a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

A hash table is simply an associative array, that is when you pass a pair of (key, value), then the key is used to compute a hash code which itself is gonna help to compute the location of a memory slot (called a bucket) in an underlying storage array (called... buckets) in which the pair you just passed and some other additional information will be saved. This is usually achieved by computing the modulo `%` of the hash code on the size of the array / buckets: `hashCode % buckets.Length`.

This sort of associative array has an average complexity of O(1) (ie. constant time) for search, insertion and deletion... except under certain circumstances that we will dig into later on. So generally speaking it's much faster to lookup something in a dictionary than say in a list or an array since you don't have to ~normally~ iterate through all the values.

If you have paid attention to what I have said until now, you will have noticed that there might already be an issue. What if the hash code computed based on our key is exactly the same as say another one? or worse a bunch of others keys? which basically mean we could just end up on the same location? How do we manage those **collisions**? Well obviously very smart folks already have given thought to this particular problem like decades ago and came up with essentially 2 main ways of solving collisions:

- [Separate Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining): basically the pair are stored in a different storage than the buckets (often called entries), for example for each bucket (each index computed) we can have a list of entries which stores the different values which have been stored at the same "index" (due to the same hashcode), basically in case of collisions you have to iterate through the keys (and find another way, other than the hashcode to to distinguish them)
- [Open Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing): everything is stored in the buckets and based on the first bucket found we check next , it also exist different schemes in the way to probe the values [Linear Probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing), [Quadratic Probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing), Double Hashing etc.)

The implementation of either of the collision resolution rules can sometimes vary a great deal. In the case of the .NET Dictionary, the data structure relies on a Separate Chaining type of collision resolution like we will see a few minutes.

Ok now let's look at how things are inserted in the .NET `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which boils down to go through code of the method below:

`private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)`

Note: after reading the insertion steps below, you can figure out the rationale behind deletion and lookup operations by inspecting the code given as a link in the sources at the bottom of my answer.

**Step 1: Give me the hash code**

There are two ways the hash code of the `TKey` key can be computed:

- One relies on the default `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` implementation comparer if you don't pass any as a parameter of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which basically is generated by `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` (implementation available [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,542680fa5b2d828d)), in case of TKey being a type different from all the usual stuff (like primitives and string) like a custom type, the `IEqualityComparer<in TKey>` will leverage the implementation (including the `override`s) of:

  - `bool Equals(object obj)`
  - `int GetHashCode()`
- The other, well, relies on the implementation of `IEqualityComparer<in TKey>` you can pass to the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` constructor.

The interface [`IEqualityComparer<in T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) looks like that:

```
// The generic IEqualityComparer interface implements methods to if check two objects are equal
// and generate Hashcode for an object.
// It is use in Dictionary class.  
public interface IEqualityComparer<in T>
{
    bool Equals(T x, T y);
    int GetHashCode(T obj);
}
```

Either way, the dictionary ends up having a first hash code using the comparer: `comparer.GetHashCode()`

**Step 2: Get the target bucket**

The hash code we got from our `TKey` key through the `IEqualityComparer<in T>` might be sometimes negative which is not really helpful if we want to get a positive index for an array...

What happens is that in order to get rid of negative values the `Int32` hashcode got by the `comparer.GetHashCode()` is "ANDed" with the `Int32.MaxValue` (ie. `2147483647` or `0x7FFFFFFF`)  (in the sense of the boolean logic: bits):

```
var hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

The target bucket (the index) is obtained as follows:

```
var targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length
```

Will also see in a moment how the `buckets` array is resized.

The `buckets` (`int[]`) is a `private` field of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` containing the indexes of of the first related slot in the `entries` field which is `Entry[]`, with `Entry` being defined as follows:

```
private struct Entry
{
    public int hashCode;
    public int next;
    public TKey key;
    public TValue value;
}
```

The `key`, `value` and `hashcode` are self-explanatory fields, regarding the `next` field, it basically indicates an index if there is another item in that chain (ie. several keys with the same hashcode), if that entry is the last item of a chain then the `next` field is set to `-1`.

Note: the `hashCode` field in the `Entry` `struct` is the one after negative value adjustment.

**Step 3: check if there is already an entry**

At that stage it is important to note that the behaviour differs depending on whether you are updating (`add = false`) or strictly inserting (`add = true`) a new value.

We will now check the entries related to the `targetBucket` starting with the first entry which is can be given by:

```
var entryIndex = buckets[targetBucket];
var firstEntry = entries[entryIndex];
```

The actual (simplified) source code with comments:

```
// Iterating through all the entries related to the targetBucket
for (var i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next)
{
    // Checked if all 
    if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && 
        comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) 
    {
        // If update is not allowed
        if (add) 
        { 
            // Argument Exception:  
            // "Item with Same Key has already been added" thrown =]
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
        }

        // We update the entry value
        entries[i].value = value;

        // Modification while iterating check field
        version++;

        return;
    } 
}
```

Note: the `version` field is field also used in other common .NET data structures (eg. `List<T>`) that helps detecting while iterating (on [`MoveNext()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,717)) (and throw the related exception).

**Step 4: check if the arrays need to be resized**

```
// The entries location in which the data will be inserted
var index = 0;

// The freeCount field indicates the number of holes / empty slotes available for insertions.
// Those available slots are the results of prior removal operations
if (freeCount > 0) 
{
    // The freeList field points to the first hole (ie. available slot) in the entries
    index = freeList;
    freeList = entries[index].next;
    // The hole is no longer available
    freeCount--;
}
else 
{
    // The entries array is full 
    // Need to resize it to make it bigger
    if (count == entries.Length)
    {
        Resize();
        targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
    }
    index = count;
    count++;
}
```

Note: the about `Resize()` call:

- It double-ish the size of the underlying arrays (`buckets` and `entries`), [like many others collections in order to avoid too many resize operations by providing ample space whenever the collection is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369503/4636721).
- Double->>ish<< since the size can only be a prime number from a precomputed set of `Int32` eg.  `3`, `7`, `11`, `17`, ..., `7199369` since using a prime can reduce the number of collisions (see [that answer on SO](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/why-is-it-best-to-use-a-prime-number-as-a-mod-in-a-hashing-function/64191#64191))

Actually early in the `Resize()` method, the new size is computed as follows:

```
public static int ExpandPrime(int oldSize)
{
    var min = 2 * oldSize;

    if ((uint) min > 2146435069U && 2146435069 > oldSize)
    {
        return 2146435069;
    }

    return HashHelpers.GetPrime(min);
}
```

**Step 5: Add the entry**

Since the dictionary is done checking holes and size, it can then finally add the entry using the computed `hashCode`, `key`, `value` and the right `index` that has just been calculated and adjust the target bucket accordingly:

```
entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;

// If the bucket already contained an item, it will be the next in the collision resolution chain.
entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
entries[index].key = key;
entries[index].value = value;
// The bucket will point to this entry from now on.
buckets[targetBucket] = index;

// Again, modification while iterating check field
version++;
```

**Bonus: string special treatment**

Quoted from the CodeProject source listed below:

> In order to make sure that each 'get' and 'add' operations will not go over more than 100 items for each bucket, a collision counter is being used.
>
> If while traversing the array to find or add an item the collision counter goes over 100 (limit is hard-coded) and the `IEqualityComparer` is of type `EqualityComparer<string>.Default`, a new `IEqualityComparer<string>` instance is being generated for alternative string hashing algorithm.
>
> If such provider is found, the dictionary will allocate new arrays and copy the content to the new arrays using the new hash code and equality provider.
>
> This optimization might be useful for a scenario where somehow your string keys are not being distributed evenly, but could also lead to massive allocations and waste of CPU time for generating new hash codes of what could be a lot of items in the dictionary.

**Usage**

Whenever you use a custom type as a key, don't forget to have implement the `IEqualityComparer` interface or to override the two Object methods (hashcode + equal) in order to not shoot yourself in the foot upon insertions.

Not only you'll avoid some bad and nasty surprises, but you can also control the distribution of items you insert. By having evenly distributed hashcodes you can avoid chaining too many items and so wasting time iterating on the related entries.

**Side note for interviewees/ers**

I would like to put emphasis on the fact knowing those implementation details for an interview is usually not a big deal (the actual implementation differs from some versions of .NET ("Regular" or Core...) plus might still be subject to changes at a later point in time)).

If someone would have asked me the question, I would either say:

- The answer you're looking for is on StackOverflow :)
- The answer you're looking for is also either on

  - [.NET Reference](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)
  - [Github - .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs)
- The answer you're looking for does not need implementation details and the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor) will suffice for most use cases.

Unless, unless... you are supposed to implement a hash tables slash dictionaries all by yourself in your day-to-day job, in which case that sort of knowledge (ie. impl. details) may come in handy or even mandatory.

Sources:

- [.NET Reference - Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)
- [Github - .NET Core - Source Code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs)
- [Reddit - Eli5: how double hashing works in .NET dictionaries?](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/ad90mc/eli5_how_double_hashing_works_in_net_dictionaries)
- [SO - How double hashing works in case of the .NET Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066180/4636721)
- [Code Project - Understanding Generic Dictionary in-depth](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/500644/%2FArticles%2F500644%2FUnderstanding-Generic-Dictionary-in-depth)
- [Mark Vincze's coding blog - Back to basics: Dictionary part 1, hash tables](https://blog.markvincze.com/back-to-basics-dictionary-part-1)
- [Mark Vincze's coding blog - Back to basics: Dictionary part 2, .NET implementation](https://blog.markvincze.com/back-to-basics-dictionary-part-2-net-implementation)

Answer (score 5):

The basic principle is:

1. Set up empty array.
2. Obtain hash-code.
3. Re-hash hash to fit size of array (e.g. if the array is 31 items in size, we can do `hash % 31`) and use this as an index.

Retrieval is then a matter of finding the index in the same way, obtaining the key if it's there, and calling `Equals` on that item.

The obvious issue here is what to do if there are two items that belong at the same index. One approach is that you store a list or similar in the array rather than the key-value pair itself, another is "reprobing" into a different index. Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages, and Microsoft use <strike>reprobing</strike> a list.

Above a certain size, the amount of reprobing (or the size of the stored lists if you took that approach) gets too large and the near-O(1) behaviour is lost, at which point the table is resized so as to improve this.

Clearly though, a really poor hash algorithm can destroy this, you can demonstrate this to yourself by building a dictionary of objects where the hashcode method is the following:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return 0;
}
```

This is valid, but horrible, and turns your near-O(1) behaviour into O(n) (and bad even as O(n) goes.

There are plenty of other details and optimisations, but the above is the basic principle.

Edit:

Incidentally, if you have a perfect hash (you know all possible values, and have a hash method that gives each such value a unique hash in a small range) it's possible to avoid the issues of reprobing that occur with more general-purpose hash-tables, and just treat the hash as an index into an array. This gives both the O(1) behaviour, and minimal memory use, but only applies when all possible values are in a small range.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Dictionary<K,V>` handles collisions using chaining (with a linked list of some kind) rather than probing.

Comment: @LukeH, yes taking a look I see that you are correct. Glad I explained both methods so :)

Comment: In .net 4 there are two arrays, one for the buckets another for the entries, and each entry is a pseudo linked list in that it can contain the index to the next entry in the same bucket.  This is an index to the same entries array.  So it feels to me like it's a hybrid between probing and a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) like practically every other dictionary implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This question got me curious, so I wrote an **ultra-fast, optimized version** of a **dictionary lookup** thats **5x (five times) faster** than the default **.NET dictionary implementation**.

I've left out error checking for brevity, however, this would be trivial to add. I've also left it un-templated to make it easier to understand.

It creates a number of nested arrays, so a lookup is a matter of chaining through object references in memory. It navigates straight to the correct object in memory, without using loops or hash tables of any description. Its reasonably memory efficient, as it only  allocates memory for what it needs. Unlike hash tables, there is never any problem with unintentional bucket collisions (unless the key is the same, of course). If you want to run the comparison yourself, I can provide the complete test project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Ultra fast dictionary, optimized for retrieval of keys consisting of 3-letter uppercase strings, where each string is 'A' to 'Z'.
/// This is 5 times faster than the default Dictionary<> implementation, but not as flexible.
/// ----start output from tester---
/// Ultra Fast Dictionary.
///   Total time for 2,000,000,000 key retrievals: 19,892 milliseconds. 0.00994600 nanoseconds per retrieval. Sum -1958822656.
/// Normal Dictionary.
///   Total time for 2,000,000,000 key retrievals: 98,397 milliseconds. 0.04919850 nanoseconds per retrieval. Sum -1958822656.
/// ----end output from tester---
/// </summary>
public class DictionaryUltraFast
{
    string[][][] dictionary;

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a string to the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        key = key.ToUpper();
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            dictionary = new string['Z' - 'A' + 1][][];
        }
        if (dictionary[key[0] - 'A'] == null)
        {
            dictionary[key[0] - 'A'] = new string['Z' - 'A' + 1][];
        }
        if (dictionary[key[0] - 'A'][key[1] - 'A'] == null)
        {
            dictionary[key[0] - 'A'][key[1] - 'A'] = new string['Z' - 'A' + 1];
        }
        dictionary[key[0] - 'A'][key[1] - 'A'][key[2] - 'A'] = value;
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return dictionary[key[0] - 'A'][key[1] - 'A'][key[2] - 'A'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a specialized data structure. It can potentially use much more memory than the usual hash table, given how the arrays are allocated. Since it is so specialized, I don't think we can compare it to a general purpose dictionary. Bucket sorting is generally a good alternative to hashing (you are using a bucket sort here).

Comment: @Gravitas wrong thread to post an excellent answer, +1 still.. Could you tell me as to what the array of array of arrays is doing here? Also how can I implement a Clear method? Do you have the complete source somewhere? You can make this generic, but I wonder if your approach does any good if string keys are of length less than 3

Comment: I also wonder how much of the 5X improvement is lost once you add error checking.  This special case requires several extra checks that you are skipping (e.g., a key of `"A"` will cause a crash).